# How to Update multiple Values in Array of object without Iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects. Is it possible to update the value of **Standard** From **"Fifth"** to **"Sixth"** (in One Go) without any Iteration? We can iterate the Array and modify the value as shown below. Is there any better approach than this?
This is my Pseudo Example, in real time I have to modify values for more than 2000 rows in an array and I have more than 100 arrays and Iterating  100 of 2000 rows takes time.

At least I need without FOR iteration.

Thanks in Advance!!!

```
var arr = [];

var obj1 = {name: 'Alice',Standard:'Fifth'};
var obj2 = {name: 'Bob',Standard:'Fifth'};
var obj3 = {name: 'Carl',Standard:'Fifth'};

arr.push(obj1, obj2, obj3);

for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
{
    arr[j].Standard="Sixth";
    console.log(arr[j]);
}
```

Comment: No, this is not possible without iteration. Depending on what you're trying to do with the array, there might be other approaches that don't require changing every single object, but since the question is about actually modifying the objects: not possible without iteration.

Comment: No matter what you're going to have to iterate over the array somehow. You can do it in less code with a `.map` (`arr.map(x => ({ ...x, Standard: 'Sixth' }))`, but there's no way to avoid looping over the whole array. If performance really is a potential problem in your application you might want to consider not using an array of objects, and storing the data some other way.

Comment: As for the update to the question, you can use `forEach()` instead of `for`, but that will slow down things even more. And the approach with `map()` in the comment above is even worse in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use higher order function in JavaScript, **forEach**

```
var arr = [];
var obj1 = {name: 'Alice',Standard:'Fifth'}; 
var obj2 = {name: 'Bob',Standard:'Fifth'}; 
var obj3 = {name: 'Carl',Standard:'Fifth'}; 
arr.push(obj1, obj2, obj3); 
arr.forEach((item) => { item.Standard = "Sixth" }) 
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your setup to use a [getter <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). If this is coming from JSON you may need to do an iteration once during object creation to modify the getter.

```js
var arr = [];

var currentStandard = 'Fifth';

var obj1 = {name: 'Alice',get Standard(){return currentStandard}};
var obj2 = {name: 'Bob',get Standard(){return currentStandard}};
var obj3 = {name: 'Carl',get Standard(){return currentStandard}};

arr.push(obj1, obj2, obj3);

console.log(arr);

currentStandard = 'Sixth';

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **map** function

```js
var arr = [];

var obj1 = {name: 'Alice',Standard:'Fifth'};
var obj2 = {name: 'Bob',Standard:'Fifth'};
var obj3 = {name: 'Carl',Standard:'Fifth'};

arr.push(obj1, obj2, obj3);

arr.map(x => x.Standard="Sixth");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Calling `map()` also performs an iteration. Furthermore, this is just bad coding. You're using `map()` to create a new array (an array of `"Sixth"` strings for that matter) which you then discard. You should use `forEach()` instead, or, as OP seems to be concerned about performance, you should just use a `for` loop as in the original question.